# error while booting ubuntu 13.10 , "mismatch in gmch_pfit.lvds_border_bits"

Tags: dual-boot, 13.10, windows-7, system-installation, gpu-driver

I'm new user of ubuntu and I just installed it using a usb stick. I did a double-boot with windows 7 and Ubuntu but when I start Ubuntu it shows this error:

```
[drm:intel_pipe_config_compare] *ERROR* mismatch in gmch_pfit.lvds_border_bits (expected 32768, found 0)
```

After a few seconds it starts normally, but I don't know what this means.
I'm using Ubuntu 13.10, how do I fix it?

Comment: This appears to be a bug which may have been fixed in the driver by now. You might find this interesting: http://linux-kernel.2935.n7.nabble.com/Excessive-WARN-s-in-Intel-915-driver-tt782187.html#none

Comment: Try updating and upgrading.  `sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt-get upgrade`